# FlexSlider dynamically loading and removing images not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet, flexslider

I got a flexslider div-Element working properly with static content.
However, when I try to add Images to it dynamically using jquery I get extremely strange and varying results.

I use the flexslider element within a Leaflet sidebar (which is, as I said working with static content) and load the images after the sidebar has completely expanded (using sidebar.on('shown', function...)).

The load function looks like this one:

```
this.loadImages = function(osm_id) {
    var nextImage = true;
    var counter = 1;

    while (nextImage) {
        var li = null;
        $.ajax({
            async : false,
            url : '/img/locations/'+osm_id+'/'+counter+'.jpg',
            type : 'HEAD',
            error : function() {
                nextImage = false;
            },
            success : function() {
                var path = '/img/locations/'+osm_id+'/'+counter+'.jpg';
                $('<img src="'+path+'">').load(function() {
                    var li = $("<li></li>");
                    $(this).appendTo(li);
                    li.appendTo($("#locationSlides"));
                }).ready(function() {
                    $("#flexslider").data("flexslider").addSlide(li);
                });
                counter++;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Jquery loads the images and adds them to the flexslider class (DOM), however, they are't shown in the browser.
Calling

```
$("#flexslider").flexslider();
```

now shows the loaded images in Firefox, but doesn't show them in Chrome either, even though they are added to the DOM in both browsers.
But loading more pictures and calling the method a second time, has no effect in Firefox either anymore.

[image: Before calling the flexslider function]

[image: after calling the flexslider function in firefox]

I absolutely can't explain this behaviour.

Comment: Why are you using a $.ajax AND a $.load ?

Comment: The ajax call to check if the image exists and the load to actually fetch it. There is certainly a more viable approach, but the loading itself works so far.

Comment: try putting this line: `$("#flexslider").flexslider();` inside `error: function()`

Comment: that makes it work for the first loading in chrome as well, but images loaded a second/third/fourth... time are neither shown in firefox nor in chrome, but are added to the DOMs...

Comment: Did you removed `$("#flexslider").flexslider();` from every place of your code and left only inside `error: function()`?

Comment: I call this function on $(window).load() too, but removing makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of testing and debugging, I couldn't make it working with flexSlider and decided to switch to [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/).
Furthermore, I found out that the jquery load function fires not just once but several times and each time the slider changes any image parameter, which sometimes results in adding more and more images.
I workarounded this with this code:

```
var errorOccured = false;
var loadNextImage = function(osm_id, id) {
    var path = '/img/locations/'+osm_id+'/'+id+'.jpg';
    $('<img src="'+path+'">').load(function() {
        if(errorOccured)
            return;
        var li = $("<li></li>");
        li.appendTo($("#bxslider"));
        $(this).appendTo(li);

        loadNextImage(osm_id, id + 1);
    }).error(function() {
        errorOccured = true;
        $("#bxslider").bxSlider({
            slideWidth : 300,
            adaptiveHeight : true
        });
    });
};

this.loadImages = function(osm_id) {
    var nextImage = true;
    var counter = 1;

    errorOccured = false;
    $("#flexsliderContainer").empty();
    $("#flexsliderContainer").append("<ul id=\"bxslider\"></ul>");


    loadNextImage(osm_id, counter);
}
```

And yes, I now threw the double image loading away :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying lots of different ideas, I got this solution to add a new image or video in Flexslider dynamically and its working fine.

JQuery code :

```
 $("#add2").change(function(event)
    {
          var fuData = document.getElementById('add2');
          var files = event.target.files;
           for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
        {
            var file = files[i];
            var filename = file.name;
            var Extension =
filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
            if(Extension == 'png' || Extension == 'jpg' || Extension == 'jpeg' || Extension == 'svg'){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e)
                {
                      var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                      img.src = e.target.result;

                      div = "<li><img src="+img.src+" /></li>";
                      $('.flexslider').data('flexslider').addSlide($(div));

                }
            }

            else if (Extension == 'mp4')
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event){
                    var video = document.createElement("video");
                    video.src = event.target.result;

                    div = " <li><video src="+video.src+" width='100%' height='500' controls></video></li>";
                    $('.flexslider').data('flexslider').addSlide($(div));
                }
            }
            else
            {
              alert(filename+' '+'is not in supported format');
              $("#add2").val('');
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id= "add2" multiple>
```

First, it will check the extension of your file, if it is image then it will go in first loop and if it is video then it will go to the second loop. I did the basic implementation in it.You can customize this code as per your requirement.